# Create a custom information page in OpenCart 1.5

Tags: opencart

I have been following the [tutorial on here](http://www.opencartnews.com/tutorials/creating-a-custom-page-in-opencart-part-1/) to create a custom page, this works if I set the address to `index.php?route=information/static`.

However I have an information page that needs to be editable using the information area on the administration, but still show a custom form on the right side of the text, I thought I could just create a new layout in the admin and set the route to `information/static` and then set the layout on the information page to the layout I just created, however when you view the page nothing from the layout is shown on the page, not even the formatting.

What am I doing wrong and how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I discovered that the layouts don't work as expected.  Luckily I had vQmod installed which I recommend everyone install!

Using vQmod I was able to modify the `information/information` template to target the layout id (in my case 20) and add the custom code.  For a complete answer I have added the full vQmod code below.

```xml
<modification>
<id>Warehouse Registration</id>
<version>1</version>
<vqmver>1</vqmver>
<author>Matthew Bagley [paramiliar.com]</author>

<file name="catalog/controller/information/information.php">
    <operation error="skip">
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
            $this->document->setTitle($information_info['title']);
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            $this->data['catid'] = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformationLayoutId($information_id);
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
<file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/information/information.tpl">
    <operation error="skip">
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[
            <div class="page-description">
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            <? if ($catid == 20){?>
                    <div style="float: left; width: 48%; margin-right: 1%;">
            <? } ?>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation error="skip">
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[
            <?php echo $description; ?>
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            <? if ($catid == 20){?>
                </div>
                <div style="float: left; width: 48%; margin-right: 1%;">Registration form is here</div>
            <? } ?>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
</modification>
```